# brother dcp-l2550dw double side scan

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, brother

Scanner is working fine by using ubuntu's default `simple scan`

I followed the instruction on brother's site

https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=dcpl2550dw_us&os=128

downloaded `Scanner driver 64bit (deb package)`

Anyways, scan is good but I thought this printer is suppose to be able for double sided scan.
I checked the setting in `simple scan` which says scan `front and back`, and I do not see any other options about double side scan though.

Does anyone know how this might work?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and advices

Edit:
I did select `all pages from feeder` when scanning

[image]

Comment: Did you follow these instructions?  https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/165348/~/how-to-duplex-scan---linux

Comment: @Terrance yes I did, UI is a bit different but yup.  I also added an image of the `preference`

Comment: Sounds like it should work then with the way you have it configured.  If it is not working, you might actually want to contact Brother support about it as it may be a bug in their software.

Comment: I have a recent model HP laser printer which will do double sided scanning however, this has to be done manually as the DF is not capable of turning the page over automatically. Could yours be the same? Using Simple Scan there is a help file which provides tips and the order in which to scan to achieve double sided scans.

Comment: @Graham if I didn't remember wrong, if I use windows with this scanner. I do  not need to turn the pages over though